# LabVIEW: multiple loops using the NXT

Tags: loops, parallel-processing, lego-mindstorms, nxt

I have two loops which, when tested separately, works!

One loop reads the sonar-sensor and controls motor B+C. The other loop also reads the sonar-sensor but controls motor A. When these are in two separate VIs (ie. no multi-looping), it works as it should.

But when I put these two loops inside the same VI, the loop which controls motor A is acting funny :-S

What am I doing wrong?

See my code [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KnX5Y.png) (in two VIs):

Answer (score 0):

Finally!!

I found a way to read the sensor from two different loops, that both uses the same input. I created a third loop, that stores the input in a 'Local Variable'.

[image]